# Issue when using Querydsl with spring boot and elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to use [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) with my spring boot starter elasticsearch project. i have added following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency> 
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId> 
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

i have also added plugin -

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I can see generated classes, but during mvn package, i can see following errors

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: QueryDsl Support has not been implemented yet.
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.getRepositoryBaseClass(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepositoryInformation(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:268)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:55)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1654)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1087)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:88)
```

I couldn't find any example for this combination. can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for some example for this combination too, but could not find any.

Apparently, **QueryDsl Support has not been implemented yet** for Spring Data Elasticsearch (Release 3.0.0) so far. Found this information while checking the code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/d30b41cc5977118a949dbf887c66d3fa87e77fb2/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/repository/support/ElasticsearchRepositoryFactory.java#L79-L81). There is an pending [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-219?jql=project%20%3D%20DATAES%20AND%20text%20~%20%22querydsl%22) on Jira for this integration too.

However, if you check the Spring Data Elasticsearch, there is a section about QueryDsl support. I'm afraid this section is out of sync with the implementation.